# Calculating Foreign Exchange Capital Loss on Margin Loan Repayment

Tags: canada, capital-gains-tax, foreign-exchange, canada-revenue-agency

Let's assume I convert 10,000 CAD to 5,000 USD and hold it for one year. During that year, I also make some trades using money borrowed from the brokerage firm (i.e. trading on margin). Afterward, I use the 5,000 USD I had previously converted to partially pay off this stock investment margin loan. However, at the time of payment, the exchange rate has changed, and the equivalent of 5,000 USD is now only 6,000 CAD.

**Did I just end up losing 4,000 CAD during the payment process? And would this be considered a qualifying foreign exchange capital loss? Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!**